# Will taking mean of sample quantiles be an unbiased estimate the population quantile?

Tags: quantiles, unbiased-estimator

Say I have $N$ samples of 100 numbers all drawn IID from the same distribution $\mathcal{D}$. For each sample, I take the 95th quantile to get $N$ sample quantiles $\hat{q}_n$. Will taking the average of these sample quantiles $\mathbb{E}[\hat{q}_n]$ estimate the true quantile of the population distribution $\mathcal{D}$?

Comment: First, $\mathbb E[\hat q_n]$ is not an estimator at all: it's a theoretical property.  Do you mean instead to take the sum of all $N$ estimates divided by $N$?  In that case, in the usual sense of a statistical estimator the answer is immediate, because the average of a bunch of estimators is still an estimator.  A more useful question to ask would concern the statistical properties of that average.  For instance, which is better: the mean of those $N$ sample quantiles or the quantile of the aggregate of all the samples?

Comment: Yes, I suppose I want to know if $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N q_n$ is approximately equal to the aggregate quantile as $N$ increases.

Comment: Consider a Bernoulli random variable with parameter $0.051$.  Then $E[\frac{1}{100}\sum_{n=1}^{100} q_{95}]$ will be close to  $\frac12$ when the desired value is $1$

Comment: Generalizing @Henry's excellent example, it is insightful to contemplate extreme cases of the situation posited in this question.  (1) Replace "100" by "1".  What can you conclude?  (2) Suppose the upper 4% of the distribution consists of values that are enormous compared to the rest of the distribution's support.  Some small fraction of the $N$ samples will have 95th percentiles that are enormous.  When you average these, how will that compare to the true 95th percentile?